# jQuery populate 2nd select menu based on value select in 1st select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I need to have 2 select menus. The selected option in the 1st select menu will populate the 2nd select menu, but only with values greater than the value selected in the 1st select menu.

The values for the 1st select menu range from 1 to 10, therefor if '4' is selected, the 2nd menu will display options from 5 to 10.

I need the 2nd select menu to be populated dynamically, rather than simple 'removing' the options from the select menu.

```
<select id="selectMenu1">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select id="selectMenu2">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind an event to selectMenu1 listening for a change, then on change
you put the selected value to variable selected and loop through the options
filtering those that are smaller than selected value and put them into selectMenu2

```js
$('#selectMenu1').on('change', function(){
  var selected = $('option:selected', this).val();
  var menu2Option = '';
  $(this).find('option').each(function(idx, ele){
    
    if(Number($(this).val()) > selected)
    {
     
      menu2Option += "<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>";
    }
  })
  $('#selectMenu2').html(menu2Option);
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectMenu1">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select id="selectMenu2">
</select>
```

Comment: This looks great, can it still work if my values contain decimals? e.g 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc.

Comment: if you have decimals, you will need to change parseInt to Numbers, as pasreInt will return only intergers

Comment: Ok could I use parseFloat for decimals? Also I need the 2nd menu start at the value greater than, not equal to the value selected in the 1st menu.

Comment: see edited answer, yes you can use  parseFloat. it is the same as Number in this situation, if you want to start at greater value just take away the equal sign

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
    $(function(){
         $('#selectMenu1').change(function(){
             var selectedVal = parseInt($('#selectMenu1').val());
             $('#selectMenu2').empty();
             for(var i = selectedVal + 1; i < 11; i++){
                 var opt = new Option(i, i);
                 $('#selectMenu2').append(opt);
             }

         });
    });

</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n0n1rhLf/7/

Answer (score 0):

You could clone the option elements, filter only what you need and replace them on the other select:

```js
$('#selectMenu1').on('change', function(){
        var menuOne = $(this), menuTwo = $('#selectMenu2');
        menuOne.children('option').clone().filter(function(index, el){
            return Number($(el).val()) > Number(menuOne.val())
        }).appendTo(menuTwo.empty());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectMenu1">
  <option value="Select">Select</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
</select>
<select id="selectMenu2">
</select>
```